# When I edit form I got 3 different value in console.log but same value showing in textbox using mat autocomplete in angular 7

Tags: angular, ngmodel, mat-autocomplete

when I edit my form I got 3 three different values in the console. But in textbox shows the same value. I am using mat autocomplete and creating a dynamic textbox.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cbsC.png

```js
for (let i=0,j=1,k=0; i < this.filters_val.chordArray; i++) {            
  this.filters.vos_tag[i] = this.response['USM_VOS'+(k.toString()+j.toString()).slice(-2)]; 
  alert(this.filters.vos_tag[i])            
  this.filters.vog_tag[i] =  this.response['USM_VOG'+(k.toString()+j.toString()).slice(-2)];
  this.filters.perf_tag[i] = this.response['USM_PERF'+(k.toString()+j.toString()).slice(-2)];
  this.filters.agc_desc[i] = this.response['USM_AGC_LEV'+(k.toString()+j.toString()).slice(-2)+'AB'];
  this.filters.agc_tag[i] = this.response['USM_AGC_LEV'+(k.toString()+j.toString()).slice(-2)+'BA'];
  this.filters.agclimit_desc[i] = this.response['USM_AGC_LIM'+(k.toString()+j.toString()).slice(-2)+'AB'];
  this.filters.agclimit_tag[i] = this.response['USM_AGC_LIM'+(k.toString()+j.toString()).slice(-2)+'BA'];
  this.filters.snr_desc[i] = this.response['USM_SNR'+(k.toString()+j.toString()).slice(-2)+'AB'];
  this.filters.snr_tag[i] = this.response['USM_SNR'+(k.toString()+j.toString()).slice(-2)+'BA'];        
  j++;                 
  console.log("JSON =>", this.filters.vos_tag[i]);      
}
          
this.loadTextBox();
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let option of options; index as idx">
  <label>PATH {{idx+1}}:</label>
  <mat-form-field> 
    <input #fy1 (keyup)="onKeyPress(fy1?.value)" type="text" [(ngModel)]="filters.vos_tag[idx]" matInput [formControl]="myControl19" [matAutocomplete]="sss">
    <mat-autocomplete #sss="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let opt of configfilteredOptions19 | async" [value]="opt.name">
          {{opt.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

[enter image description here][1]

Comment: please reformat your post

Comment: Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers

Comment: Will anyone please solve this problem

Comment: Vimal if you have any solution then please let me know ASAP